# What is the internal load factor of a sets in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, set, load-factor

I am trying to find out what the internal load factor is for the Python sets. For dictionary which uses a hash table with a load factor of 0.66 (2/3) is. The number of buckets start at 8 and when the 6th key is inserted the number of buckets increases to 16
The table below shows the shift in buckets.

| bucket | shift |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 5 |
| 16 | 10 |
| 32 | 21 |
| 64 | 42 |
| 128 | 85 |

This can be seen with de following Python code where the size of a dictionary and sets is shows with the getsizeof method:

```
import sys
d = {}
s = set()

for x in range(25):
    d[x] = 1
    s.add(x)
    print(len(d), sys.getsizeof(d), sys.getsizeof(s))
```

| # of elements | memory used for dict | memory used for sets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 232 | 216 |
| 2 | 232 | 216 |
| 3 | 232 | 216 |
| 4 | 232 | 216 |
| 5 | 232 | 728 |
| 6 | 360 | 728 |
| 7 | 360 | 728 |
| 8 | 360 | 728 |
| 9 | 360 | 728 |
| 10 | 360 | 728 |
| 11 | 640 | 728 |
| 12 | 640 | 728 |
| 13 | 640 | 728 |
| 14 | 640 | 728 |
| 15 | 640 | 728 |
| 16 | 640 | 728 |
| 17 | 640 | 728 |
| 18 | 640 | 728 |
| 19 | 640 | 2264 |
| 20 | 640 | 2264 |
| 21 | 640 | 2264 |
| 22 | 1176 | 2264 |
| 23 | 1176 | 2264 |
| 24 | 1176 | 2264 |
| 25 | 1176 | 2264 |

The above table shows that the shift in the buckets correct is for the dictionary, but not for the sets. The memory in sets is different.

I am trying to find out what the load factor is for a set. Is that also 2/3? Or am I doing something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, it's about 3/5. See the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Objects/setobject.c#L175-L177):

```
if ((size_t)so->fill*5 < mask*3)
    return 0;
return set_table_resize(so, so->used>50000 ? so->used*2 : so->used*4);
```

`fill` is the number of occupied table cells (including "deleted entry" markers), and `mask` is 1 less than the total table capacity.

Comment: Would you imagine this is going to be interpreter specific? e.g. pypi vs cpython, or between python versions?

Comment: @flakes: Absolutely. CPython [changed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5cd87a8d61246b0a6233bfb8503d4718b693cef0) it from 2/3 back in 2017. I don't know what Pypy or Jython do, but they're not bound to CPython's implementation decisions.