# Order of a set in Python

Tags: python, hash, set, hashtable

I assumed that when we iterate through a set, the order in which the iteration occurs is based on the increasing order of the hashes of the hash table that corresponds to the set.
I wanted to test this out and wrote a code for the same.

I read somewhere that the hash table doubles in size in Python when it is filled over 60%. Initially, it has eight slots. So, if I fill up six of those slots, it should have 16 slots due to resizing. The hashes stored in them should be `hash(x)%16`, then.

```py
>>> t = tuple(hash(i)%16 for i in (chr(i) for i in range(97, 103)))
```

This creates a tuple `t` with modulo 16 of the hashes of characters 'a' through 'f'. I repeated this till I got no collisions and got `t = (4, 3, 1, 7, 12, 9)`. I expected that when I print `set('abcdef')`, it would display `{'c','b','a','d','f','e'}`, but the output was `{'c','d','f','b','a','e'}`.

However, if I instead did

```py
>>> t = tuple(hash(i)%32 for i in (chr(i) for i in range(97, 103)))
```

I got `t = (20, 19, 1, 7, 28, 9)`, which predicts the order `{'c','d','f','b','a','e'}` correctly.

Every time I did it for six elements and '%32', the right order was predicted.

So, what's going on here? Is the hash table's size 32? Why is that?

Comment: Generally, all hash-tables are considered unordered. Two wildly different values with different hashes might end up in the same bucket.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not in CPython's implementation (as of today). Buckets hold only a single value. But you're right in general, and CPython could change to use more advanced hash tables behind the scenes without breaking API's.

Comment: You can get the number of allocated entries with `(sys.getsizeof(my_set) - sys.getsizeof(set())) // 16` (the 16 is correct for current 64-bit CPython versions). Note that if there are only 8 entries then they are part of the base set object so this formula will give 0.

Comment: @MSalters do you mean switching from open addressing to chaining? Why would this be "more advanced?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at implementation details, and then summarizing them. You left out one critical detail: for small sets, the hash table size is multiplied by 4.
[What is the internal load factor of a sets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75291343/what-is-the-internal-load-factor-of-a-sets-in-python)

Note that this is all subject to change. As the linked question notes, the load factor has changed from 2/3 to 3/5 in 2017. Reasonable code does not depend on this.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer! I don't intend to rely on the 'order' of a set in any programs, I just wanted to test if what I thought about it was indeed true :)